# Create new entry in mongodb with an array as a sub-object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My mongoose schema looks like this

```
{
   name: String,
   posts: [
       {
            title: String,
            description: String,
            tags: [String]
       }
   ]
}
```

and I need to push an entry to one existing entry i.e.

```
item = {
   title: 'Abc',
   description: 'abcabcabcabc',
   tags: [
       'aa', 'bb', 'cc'
   ]
}
```

then what be the way to do it?
I tried
`User.updateOne({ _id: id }, { $push: { posts: item } });`.

If posts.tags was not an array of objects but just a single value, then the command works. But the problem arises when an array of the same has to be passed.

Edit: The object is created with the specified value, but the `tags` arrays is empty

Answer (score 1):

you cannot directly push all the array of values. Use $each to push the array of values to posts array like so,

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000")
},
{
  $push: {
    posts: {
      $each: [
        {
          title: "Abc",
          description: "abcabcabcabc",
          tags: [
            "aa",
            "bb",
            "cc"
          ]
        },
        {
          title: "Abc",
          description: "abcabcabcabc",
          tags: [
            "aa",
            "bb",
            "cc"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/QWy4Wu4ldvl